# Detect font in a image

Tags: image, fonts, detection

I have a very strange requirement that the font of text in a JPG image should be detected. 
How can it be done? I wonder is there any way to do so.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the particlar font, or is it just any font?

Comment: yes.. there can be 3 specific fonts (Lucida console, Calibri and ariel) all at once present in JPG

Comment: And which language do you want to use for this?

Comment: Is there any readily available tool to detect the font? If no I would like to develop it using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You can try these services:

1. [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) I think that is the most accurate service to identify the font in a image, not fully automated and with limitations (it will only match what is in the MyFonts library) I recommend to use this if you want something really reliable
2. [Matcherator](https://www.fontspring.com/matcherator) It will also match what is in its own library, less accurate, I can not give you any more information about it but i'm secure it's a good alternative
3. [Typefont](https://github.com/Sirvasile/Typefont) I think is less accurate than the others 2 and and it contains a really small library but it's a JavaScript open source project where you can easily add new fonts to the library, although I am the author I do not really feel comfortable recommending it in the state in which it is currently, but you can contribute if you really need it
4. [Whatfontis](https://www.whatfontis.com/) I recently discovered whatfontis which detect both commercial and free fonts pretty accurately. The only small drawback is that on mobile is kind of slow, but on desktop does a very good job.

I hope to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Another good site for detected your front from jpg.
It's work for me fine.  [Fontsquirrel matcherator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator)

Comment: Awful results on my end and they just seems to push premium fonts to you.

Comment: @Sigex Thanks for your information but I checked it after seeing your comment, after searching i got 15 free fonts in search result and 11 paid fonts, so i hope it depend on which fonts actually your looking.