# How to recognize the language and font of text from the image?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, ocr, tesseract

Basically, I need to find a way to recognize any text and any characters from the image. I have to work with the Tesseract and for plain text in most languages, it works well, when I pass the language before running the process using the `-l` tag. But for this case, that language should be defined already.

My platform based on Node.js and I'm using my own lib to work with Tesseract using the Node.js child processes.

So the goal is the following. How to recognize text language and font from the image using Node.js or Python? The command also can be run as a child process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your Tesseract  work?

Comment: My lib just runs the Tesseract commands as a Node.js child process. It doesn't matter actually.

Comment: Dear @Johnny I need to recognize text language and text font from the image. Tesseract is able to recognize the text easily when we transmit the language.  I have checked the pytesseract. If you can share the code snippet to recognize the language and font it will be great.

Comment: Maybe you can make your own model of font recognition using CV. I will choose the free API.

Comment: Actually, I didn't get the point why do you remove your answer and comments. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's not the right answer and can lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552271/detect-font-in-a-image/43599355#43599355 this is a good idea